How to control the direction of fill
I'm trying to use Alt+F to fill the bottom of these ear models
Beacuse of some reasons, I unchecked the beauty function and find the direction of the face is different.
Is it because of different boundary shapes that lead to different directions? Is there any way to control the direction?
you can get my file from  and select the border by vertex group easily


select two vertices on your edges, press F and press F and ...again and again
(or just hold f)

to fill the "other" side you can either select the two vertices of that side or in edge mode select the edge and hold f again:

Important note: This fill is only available with the built-in F2 addon enabled

Important note: This fill is only available with a built-in F2 addon enabled.

thx! i added that to my answer.
